# Batch filre runs on Win erver 2003 but not on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, windows-server-2003

I have the following batch script:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "*.*" /B /O:D') DO (SET %NewestFile=%%I)
echo %NewestFile%
```

on a `Windows 2003 Server` it works as expected and outputs the newest file

```
IntelMPFilesPath=C:\Programme\Intel\NGSMS\MPFiles
IntelMPFilesPath=C:\Programme\Intel\NGSMS\MPFiles
test.bat
```

but running the same batch file on `Windows 7` gives the following:

```
Die Umgebungsvariable "I" ist nicht definiert.
Die Umgebungsvariable "I" ist nicht definiert.
Die Umgebungsvariable "I" ist nicht definiert.
Die Umgebungsvariable "I" ist nicht definiert.
ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
```

Does anybody know if there is that big of a difference between the Win7 and the Srv2003 command shell?

Comment: you can remove `"delims=|"` and better set `"delims="`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's working in Server 2003.  You have an extra `%`.

You should remove the `%` in `SET %NewestFile`:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "*.*" /B /O:D') DO (SET NewestFile=%%I)
echo %NewestFile%
```

Comment: hmm tanks. it is trange but i think i already tried it but that solved my problem thanks nate